# Differrences between PHPMyAdmin and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Does it exist any difference between MySQL and PHPMyAdmin? arent they DBMS? I really dont find the difference between these two, I read the concepts so I know they are not the same but I cant spot the differences or when should use one instead of another one. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is a database *server*. It stores data, and runs queries on it that clients send to it.

PHPMyAdmin is a database *client*. It provides a user interface (written as a web app) that sends queries to the database server and displays what it sends back.

The difference is rather akin to the difference between Google Chrome (although Chrome is a desktop app rather than a web app) and Apache HTTPD.

Comment: so when i use xaamp and i open phpmyadmin and it shows some databases, those databases were created in mysql and phpmyadmin is just showing them?